# Unity3D Multiplayer logins

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have this c# script that looks just like this

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using WebRequest;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Runtime.Remoting;

public class Login_Button : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}
public static string UserName;
public static string Password;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
public void UserInput (string UserInput)
{
    UserName = UserInput;
}

public void PassInput (string PassInput)
{
    Password = PassInput;
}

public void UserName_Checked(string Menu_MultiLobby)
{
    string ActiveCheck = "*************/api.php" + UserName + "&p=" + Password;
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(ActiveCheck);
    request.Method = "GET";
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string Active = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    response.Close();
    if (Active == "accepted")
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(Menu_MultiLobby);
    }
    else if (Active == "wrong")
    {

    }
  }
}
```

In Unity3D I'm getting this error.

```
Assets/Login_Button.cs(4,7): error CSO246: The type of namespace name 'WebRequest' could not be found.
```

I was using MonoDevelop and I put the .dll into the references. Do I need to put it somewhere else? Also in case your wondering this is made so it will use the php to connect to a mySQL and check if account exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`WebRequest` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) is in the `System.Net` namespace, not the WebRequest namespace (that does not exist).  Specify

```
using System.Net;
```

instead of

```
using WebRequest;
```

Better yet, simply remove `using WebRequest`, since `System.Net` is already in your namespaces list.

Comment: but he is using `System.Net`! isn't he?

Comment: I already clarified that.  See my last paragraph.  He's getting the error because `WebRequest` is not a valid namespace.

Comment: That fixed that problem but the Application.LoadLevel(); doesn't seem to be working now :(